# How to import products very fast into my site from csv file

Tags: magento-1.7, import, dataflow

I am beginner of Magento..

I have a CSV data sheet file that contains a lot of products. When I try to run using Dataflow, it takes too much time to import products from CSV into my store..

Do you have any idea on how to increase the speed of Dataflow or any good extension that does this job?

Please, kindly tell me!

Comment: Write own parser, it takes about 8-10 hours if you have normal Magento skills like programmatically creating products

Comment: +1 on user3553's Magmi suggestion. Please don't double post your questions on the forums, either post it in the main SO site or here, not both.

Answer (score 4):

This opensource project [Magmi](http://sourceforge.net/projects/magmi/)

will import 75products per second on my system ,
compared to 1 product per 2minutes on magento's import dataflow.

Keep in mind when you upload these files that you make sure no one else can access it. ( ht access etc )

Comment: Upvote for MAGMI. And you're right about restricting access as indeed it has security hole. Those who is looking for a secure MAGMI integration into Magento admin with all plugins installed and configured, can take a look at [this](http://productuploader.magelynx.com) one.

Answer (score 0):

If you need to update existing products by csv import than include only those column which you want to update with SKU. yes, sku has required column then you can include columns which are going to update the product attributes. It imports products so fast!!!!